# Edit Instagram profile bio with Python

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I need to know how to edit my Instagram bio with Python. I've already made a program that gets my followers count with `instaloader` and I wanted to update my bio every x seconds with my number of followers. Is there any way I could do that?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this: https://github.com/ping/instagram_private_api

You can update the bio using `edit_profile()`: [Docs](https://instagram-private-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#instagram_private_api.Client.edit_profile)